# configure webpack2 from SCSS extract plugin

Tags: sass, webpack-2

i am trying to configure webpack2 for compiling SCSS to CSS and extract it one file with

> "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.3"

plugin avaiable as latest...

here is my webpacke config file content...

```
var path = require('path');

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (env) {
  return {
        entry: './index.js',
    output: {
      path: './dist',
            filename: 'app.js'
    },

    module: {

      rules: [

        /*
         * Extract CSS files from .src/styles directory to external CSS file
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: 'css-loader'
          })
        },

        /*
         * Extract and compile SCSS files from .src/styles directory to external CSS file
         */
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: 'css-loader!sass-loader'
          }),
                    include: ['./app.scss']
        },

      ]

    },

    /**
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [

      /**
       * Plugin: ExtractTextPlugin
       * Description: Extracts imported CSS files into external stylesheet
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
       */
      new ExtractTextPlugin('./dist/app.css')
        ]

  };
}
```

Can anybody please help that whats wrong with this configurations....

Neither is compile nor extract to file....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to separate (scss/css) the builds into separate queries. See here for documentation: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/. You should be able to do something like this:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: new ExtractTextPlugin.extract([ 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ])
}
```